# Initialize const array in a variadic constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, constants, variadic

I want to initialize a const array from variadic parameters. But with this code only the first value in the values arrays is initialized, the rest are zeroes. **How can I fix it?**

I never dealt with variadic parameters and I don't know how do they basically work.

```
struct Object
{
    const int values[8];

    constexpr Object()
        : values{}
    {}

    constexpr Object(int values...)
        : values{values}
    {}
}

// in main.cpp :
Object o = { 1, 2, 3 };
```

**Additional question**: can I write a class template and make its array size to be equal to variadic parameters count?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since C++17 we can take advantage of [user-defined deduction guides](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction#User-defined_deduction_guides):

```
template <class T, size_t N>
class Object
{
    T d_[N];
public:
    Object() = default;

    template <class... Ts>
    constexpr Object(Ts... others) : d_{others...} {}

    constexpr auto size() const noexcept { return N; }

    constexpr auto operator[] (size_t i) const noexcept { return d_[i]; }
};

// Deduction guide
template <class T, class... Ts> Object(T, Ts...) -> Object<T, 1 + sizeof...(Ts)>;
```

Live, [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/LVqEjokM05pil3rY).

Comment: That's amazing, that's what i want: to go from variadic parameters to their number N and build some Object<N>

Answer (score 2):

To fix first code you could write:

```
template<class ... Values>
constexpr Object(Values ... values)
    : values{values...}
{
    static_assert(sizeof...(values) == 8);
}
```

Regarding your additional question:

```
template<int ... ints>
struct Object2
{
    const int values[sizeof...(ints)]{ints...};
};
Object2<1,21,3> o2; // array with 3 elements
std::cout << o2.values[1] << std::endl; // 21
```

Size of array needs to be known at compile-time. So you cannot specify array's length when constructor is called, it is too late. But you can use non-type parameters when instantiating template.

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/TCPyR3)